# Why does solc output bytecode that is not in valid hex format?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, solc

I compile my solidity file using the following command:

```
solc Encoder.sol --bin --abi --optimize -o <output_dir>/
```

Then I try to deploy it in Geth:

```
Encoder = eth.contract([<abi file content>])
deployEncoder = {from:eth.coinbase, data:"0x<bin file content>", gas:2000000}>}
```

`getPartialInstanceEncoder = Encoder.new([], deployEncoder)`

The last line throws an exception. Looking closer into the bin file content, I figured out that the bin file contains several invalid characters, either '$' or '_'. What is the reason for this?

I uploaded my bin file here (since it is too large for the text here), you can search for the characters in your browser: https://file.io/OIFtZM

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess because the link seems to be dead, but maybe you're using libraries?

From https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.11/using-the-compiler.html:

> If your contracts use [libraries](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.11/contracts.html#libraries), you will notice that the bytecode contains substrings of the form `__$53aea86b7d70b31448b230b20ae141a537$__`. These are placeholders for the actual library addresses. The placeholder is a 34 character prefix of the hex encoding of the keccak256 hash of the fully qualified library name. The bytecode file will also contain lines of the form `// <placeholder> -> <fq library name>` at the end to help identify which libraries the placeholders represent. Note that the fully qualified library name is the path of its source file and the library name separated by `:`. You can use `solc` as a linker meaning that it will insert the library addresses for you at those points:
>
> Either add `--libraries "file.sol:Math:0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890 file.sol:Heap:0xabCD567890123456789012345678901234567890"` to your command to provide an address for each library or store the string in a file (one library per line) and run `solc` using `--libraries fileName`.